Safari renders completely different color than chrome and external monitor as well
I'm facing really weird behavior when css div background color attribute rendered on browser.
This is desired color. Chrome browser
Safari, MacBook Pro M2
Safari, External LG monitor connected via HDMI
The color is not slightly different it's just DIFFERENT!
Plus, on safari, color is different on external monitor even the browser is same.
It doesn't occur on Chrome. .png(or any other image format) file is also fine. It renders same color throughout the browser or equipment.
Why is this happening? I don't even know what keyword to search about this.
I tried other color shades, it gives back same result no matter what color is.
And this is not only my local device problem. It behaves same on other's MacBook or iMac.
Mobile safari is also fine.
Environment:
Next.js 14.0.4
, tailwindcss 3.4.1
Below is original code with tailwindcss, nextjs.
<div className="w-[1082.67px] h-[942.47px] relative">
    <div className="w-[612.32px] h-[733.02px] left-[372.45px] top-0 absolute origin-top-left rotate-[30.54deg] bg-lime-300 rounded-full blur-[110px]"></div>
    <div className="w-[327.26px] h-[443.83px] left-[969.39px] top-[259px] absolute origin-top-left rotate-[69.75deg] bg-green-500 rounded-full blur-[110px]"></div>
</div>

And this is snippet with only Reactjs(code is just auto generated by figma plugin)
It's not reproduced with this environment. But still, chrome shows color and safari don't.


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", position: "relative" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            width: 768.94,
            height: 803.25,
            left: 496.6,
            top: 0,
            position: "absolute",
            transform: "rotate(23.87deg)",
            background: "#BFEE5C",
            borderRadius: 9999,
            filter: "blur(241px)",
          }}
        />
        <div
          style={{
            width: 342.17,
            height: 576.05,
            left: 1292.52,
            top: 259,
            position: "absolute",
            transform: "rotate(63.80deg)",
            background: "#29CA6D",
            borderRadius: 9999,
            filter: "blur(241px)",
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>




Would be the color-profile (not) kicking in. But we need to know how you produce that image in the first place to be able to help you.

Please edit your question to include a code snippet which contains an element set up to have the same background color you are using on your webpage. In order to help you debug the problem we need to be able to see and reproduce the problem for ourselves. At the very least, please paste the relevant parts of your HTML and CSS into your post.

@Kaiido
Thank you for your comment. I've added additional info and snippet.

@BrettDonald
Thank you for your comment. I've added additional info and snippet.

What I see from that snippet is that Safari has a bug where they can't render that big of a blur in that clipped canvas. Might be worth a bug report, but this filter will be slow everywhere. You'd probably be better rendering it once as a png, or to sue a gradient + smaller blur instead.

I think this runnable snippet approximates the effect you want, and uses the colours you have used. But I can’t reproduce the problem you describe: on Safari my M1 MacBook Pro, this snippet produces the correct greenish colours on both the laptop screen and my external screens.


.d1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #bfee5c;
  transform: rotate(24deg);
  filter: blur(250px);
}

.d2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #29ca6d;
  transform: rotate(64deg);
  filter: blur(250px);
}
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>



Update
As per comments below, the problem was observed on older versions of macOS and Safari, and was solved by updating to macOS 14.5 and Safari 17.5.

Unfortunately your code snippet has same problem in my laptop. :(
When I run the snippet, it still doesn't appear in Safari. Anyway thank you for your answer. I'll check on other devices.

So when you run my snippet in Chrome, you see shades of green, but when you run it in Safari, you see nothing? Which version of Safari are you using? (I am using 17.5 on macOS 14.5.)

Oh, I've run your snippet on M1 Air and colors appear on Safari but gives same different color shades.

I'm using M2 pro: 16.6 on Ventura 13.5. M1 air: 15.4 on Monterey 12.3.1. I'll update those two and see same thing happens.

Wow. I upgraded to 14.5 and problem solved. Was this just macOS bug? Ridiculous. By the way I couldn't even know about this without you. Thank you so much.

My pleasure. You can reward me by marking my answer as the accepted answer. Thanks.
